# PHP-SQL: Counting and sorting if values set in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with following stucture:

[image: table structure]

Now I would like to count the amount of "yes" per column over a not defined amount of lines and output a list in descending order:
C3 -> 3x
C1 -> 1x
...

with something like this i can get the number of yes'es but can not order the list:

`count(case when C_1 = '[\"yes\"]' then 1 end) C1_count`

Is there an elegant way to loop and sort true the table count and sort to generate the output list? And also be able in cas that C_11 will be added to expand the code?

Thanks a lot for assistance.

Comment: . . I added the MySQL tag based on your comment.  However, in general, you should tag your questions with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Postgresql

```sql
select col_no, yes_count from unnest
(
 (select array
 [
  count(case when C_1 = 'yes' then 1 end),
  count(case when C_2 = 'yes' then 1 end),
  ...
  count(case when C_10 = 'yes' then 1 end)
 ]::integer[] from _table
 )
) with ordinality as t(yes_count, col_no)
order by yes_count desc;
```

It seems to me that your table design can be improved. And BTW pls. tag your RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am using MySQLi. I will try to apply the code to my table, wich is already there and I need to deal with :(

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       ( (c_1 = 'Yes') + (c_2 = 'Yes') + . . . + (c_10 = 'Yes')
       ) as num_yes
from t
order by num_yes desc;
```

Actually, I realize that the above assumes that the blank values are actually empty strings, not `NULL`.  To handle `NULL`s use `NULL`-safe comparisons:

```
select t.*,
       ( (c_1 <=> 'Yes') + (c_2 <= >'Yes') + . . . + (c_10 <=> 'Yes')
       ) as num_yes
from t
order by num_yes desc;
```